# Networkx MultiDiGraph visualization with Plotly (or mpl)?

Tags: python, plotly, networkx, graphviz

I have a `nx.MultiDiGraph()` instance `G`, which works great if I write out a dotfile from `nx` and visualize it using `dot` or other GraphViz command line tools:

```
# write .dot file from Python
nx.drawing.nx_agraph.write_dot(G, 'graph.dot')

# from the command line 
$ dot -Tpng graph.dot > graph.png'
```

Yields the following lovely image:

[image: dot output]

I would very much like to be able to replicate this kind of plot using `plotly` or `matplotlib`, especially such that the edges can be hover-able to display some labels. However, I cannot find any documentation on how to achieve this for a `MultiDiGraph`.

I have tried the following, which results in only a single edge label between each pair of nodes.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import networkx as nx

G = # the nx.MultiDiGraph()

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

edge_x = []
edge_y = []
for edge in G.edges():
    x0, y0 = pos[edge[0]]
    x1, y1 = pos[edge[1]]
    edge_x.append(x0)
    edge_x.append(x1)
    edge_x.append(None)
    edge_y.append(y0)
    edge_y.append(y1)
    edge_y.append(None)

edge_trace = go.Scatter(
    x=edge_x, y=edge_y,
    line=dict(width=0.5, color='#888'),
    hoverinfo='all',
    mode='lines')

node_x = []
node_y = []
for node in G.nodes():
    x, y = pos[node]
    node_x.append(x)
    node_y.append(y)

node_trace = go.Scatter(
    x=node_x, y=node_y,
    mode='markers',
    hoverinfo='all',
    marker=dict(
        showscale=True,
        colorscale='YlGnBu',
        reversescale=True,
        color=[],
        size=10,
        line_width=2))

fig_graph = go.Figure(data=[edge_trace, node_trace],
             layout=go.Layout(
                titlefont_size=16,
                showlegend=False,
                hovermode='closest',
                margin=dict(b=20,l=5,r=5,t=40),
                xaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, showticklabels=False),
                yaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, showticklabels=False))
                )
```